# Akka migration from 2.0 to 2.1

Tags: scala, akka

I have started working with Actors, and was following a simple example as mention in the [Getting Started Guide.](http://typesafe.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started-with-akka-scala.html#bootstrap-the-calculation)

Specs:
Scala Version: 2.9.2

Akka Version: 2.0

I ran the example and it ran well. Then I changed by `sbt` build script to:

> name := "PracAkka"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.9.2"
>
> resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
>
> libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10"  % "2.1.2"

i.e. I started using `Akka 2.1.2`. There were small changes and as per the [migration guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/project/migration-guide-2.0.x-2.1.x.html), I made the respective changes. But still I am getting the below error:

> class file needed by Props is missing. reference type ClassTag of package reflect refers to nonexisting symbol.

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear I'd say: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/project/migration-guide-2.0.x-2.1.x.html

(I.e. Akka 2.1.x is for Scala 2.10)

Answer (score 1):

From the sbt [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies)

> If you use groupID %% artifactID % revision rather than groupID %
>   artifactID % revision (the difference is the double %% after the
>   groupID), sbt will add your project's Scala version to the artifact
>   name. This is just a shortcut. You could write this without the %%:
>
> **libraryDependencies += "org.scala-tools" % "scala-stm_2.9.1" % "0.3"**
>
> Assuming the scalaVersion for your build is 2.9.1, the following is
>   identical:
>
> **libraryDependencies += "org.scala-tools" %% "scala-stm" % "0.3"**
>
> The idea is that many dependencies are compiled for multiple Scala
>   versions, and you'd like to get the one that matches your project.

Your script seems to be getting Akka for scala 2.10 in `"akka-actor_2.10"` try renaming to your scala version.